# Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-1}$ in the annulus $1<|z-2|<3$

So I use partial fractions and get

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z-1}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{z+1}$$

I asked some question earlier today about these manipulations to geometric series  but I still don't get it really. This is what I am doing so far

$$\frac{1}{z-1} = \frac{1}{1--(z-2)}$$

and then I just switch it over to a geometric series, but is this even right? Im so lost when it comes to the radius of convergence and how to manipulate the terms correctly. How should I think?

Comment: As I have mentioned in some comments, for $1\lt|z-2|\lt3$, the geometric series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(z-2)^k$ does not converge. This is why I use the series $$\frac1{z-1}=-\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}(2-z)^k$$ which *does* converge for $1\lt|z-2|\lt3$.

Answer (score 1):

First we introduce $-2+2$ around $z$:
$$-\frac{1}{1-z}=-\frac{1}{1-(z-2+2)}$$

Now lets get the $+2$ out of the brackets:
$$=-\frac{1}{-1-(z-2)}=\frac{1}{1+(z-2)}$$

Now we use the geometric series
$$=1-(z-2)+(z-2)^2-(z-2)^3\pm \cdots$$

Lets look at the general case. We want the Laurent series in the anulus  $b-1<|z-b|<b+2$, where b is positive:

$$\frac{1}{a-z}=\frac{1}{a-(z-b+b)}=\frac{1}{a-b-(z-b)}=\frac{1}{a-b}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-b}{a-b}}=\frac{1}{a-b}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-b)^n}{(a-b)^n}$$

Comment: For $1\lt|z-2|\lt3$, the geometric series $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(z-2)^k$ does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

Since $|z-2|\gt1$, we expand $\frac1{z-1}$ as a series in $\frac1{2-z}$.
Since $|z-2|\lt3$, we expand $\frac1{z+1}$ as a series in $\frac{2-z}3$.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{z^2-1}
&=\frac12\left(\frac1{z-1}-\frac1{z+1}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(-\frac1{(2-z)-1}-\frac1{3-(2-z)}\right)\\
&=-\frac12\underbrace{\sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1}(2-z)^k}_{\text{converges: $|2-z|\gt1$}}
-\frac16\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{2-z}3\right)^k}_{\text{converges: $|2-z|\lt3$}}
\end{align}
$$